# What is the best datasource for global administrative divisions?

Tags: data-request

We are setting up a new architecture of our system. One of the key components is the administrative division of each country around the globe. We are using Bing to map this structure. Sadly, Bing doesn't want to share their administrative division structure, although you would see them on the map if you search for a location. Google offers the same data.

To have an initial load in our systems I'm looking for a dataset that contains this structure. The only source I could find is Mapanet, but that's quite expensive and the reviews on data quality are also not very promising. Therefore, I'm looking for your expertise on this. Can someone help me with a good data source on this, both with a fair price and good data quality?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact use case you may be able to use the [GADM data](https://gadm.org/), the [licence](https://gadm.org/license.html) lacks openness to a degree but may be ok for you.

> GADM license - 
>   The data are freely available for academic use and other non-commercial use. Redistribution, or commercial use, is not allowed without prior permission. Using the data to create maps for academic publishing is allowed.